# Gunicorn not creating .sock file on AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm stuck with creating a Django web app following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#check-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file

I think I've read all related questions on SO:

[django gunicorn sock file not created by wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919053/django-gunicorn-sock-file-not-created-by-wsgi)

[Gunicorn not generating sock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244074/gunicorn-not-generating-sock-file)

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1166

None of them helped.

I'm following each step exactly as described but still the myapp.sock file is not created.

The main project directory is `/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel`
It's content:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-104:~/puchalatravel$ ls -l
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   40960 Sep  4 09:37 db.sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu     545 Sep  4 07:42 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu www-data  4096 Sep  4 09:32 puchalatravel
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu    4096 Sep  4 07:41 puchalatravelenv
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu    4096 Sep  4 09:34 static
```

Access to the folder:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-104:~$ ls -l
total 1616
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Aug 30 07:25 eb-virt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1642522 Aug 30 07:11 get-pip.py
drwxrwxr-x 6 ubuntu www-data    4096 Sep  4 09:37 puchalatravel
```

Content of `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravelenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock puchalatravel.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Content of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/puchalatravel`

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 sserver {
listen 8000;
    server_name ec2-18-188-249-6.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock;
    }
}
```

I've ran

```
pkill gunicorn
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Several times, no effect whatsoever.

Output of `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-09-04 09:56:51 UTC; 18min ago
Main PID: 19906 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 04 09:56:46 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:46 +0000] [19906] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Sep 04 09:56:46 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:46 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Sep 04 09:56:47 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:47 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Sep 04 09:56:48 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:48 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Sep 04 09:56:49 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:49 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Sep 04 09:56:50 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:50 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Sep 04 09:56:51 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[19906]: [2018-09-04 09:56:51 +0000] [19906] [ERROR] Can't connect to /home/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock
Sep 04 09:56:51 ip-172-31-35-104 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 09:56:51 ip-172-31-35-104 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 04 09:56:51 ip-172-31-35-104 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Could this be related to AWS EC2 setup? Gunicorn works to serve the page directly to port 8000 but not via the socket as it's not created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gunicorn.service file configures gunicorn to create the file in "/home/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock" instead of "/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock".